# MacOS keyboard layout not working on linux trough barrier(synergy)

Tags: macos, archlinux, keyboard-layout, barrier

my issue is rather complicated, so I do not expect to find a solution, but maybe someone has had the same issue before me.

My workspace is composed of 2 computers, a mac and a Pc running linux Manjaro.
To avoid having 2 keyboards, I use the one of my mac, with layout CH-DE.
I'm having some trouble using *Barrier(Synergy)* between the mac as server and a linux as client.

My issue is: when typing `alt`+`Shift`+`7` to write "`\`" this does not work on my client machine where instead I get: `/`.

On both machines I have set the keyboard layout to *macintosh CH-DE* and **every combination without `alt`+`Shift`** works correctly.
The key combination `altgr`+`Shift`+`7` works perfectly fine **if i'm using an external wired keyboard** keeping the keyboard layout to *macintosh CH-DE*.

I had to struggle with Barrier even to reach this situation. I had to use a config file on my mac that looks like this:

```
section: screens
    MBP:
        halfDuplexCapsLock = false
        halfDuplexNumLock = false
        halfDuplexScrollLock = false
        xtestIsXineramaUnaware = false
        preserveFocus = false
        switchCorners = none 
        switchCornerSize = 0
    manjaro:
        alt = altgr
        halfDuplexCapsLock = false
        halfDuplexNumLock = false
        halfDuplexScrollLock = false
        xtestIsXineramaUnaware = false
        preserveFocus = false
        switchCorners = none 
        switchCornerSize = 0
end

section: options
    relativeMouseMoves = true
    screenSaverSync = true
    win32KeepForeground = false
    clipboardSharing = true
    switchCorners = none +top-left +top-right +bottom-left +bottom-right 
    switchCornerSize = 0
    keystroke(<) = keystroke(<,*)
    keystroke(Shift+>) = keystroke(Shift+>,*)
end
```

Note that I had to map the `alt` key to `altgr` to make it work.
Also the `<` didn't work properly: adding `keystroke(<) = keystroke(<,*)`
solved the issue.

So, I tried to add the following possibilities to solve the `alt`+`Shift`+`7` problem:

```
keystroke(Alt+Shift+/) = keystroke(Alt+Shift+/,*)
keystroke(Alt+Shift+/) = keystroke(AltGr+Shift+/,*)
keystroke(Alt+Shift+7) = keystroke(Alt+Shift+7,*)
keystroke(Alt+Shift+7) = keystroke(AltGr+Shift+7,*)
```

But none of those options worked.

My question is if there is an (other) way to solve that issue?

Thank you in advance for reading my question and your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By chance I found the solution for XFCE working for any keyboard layout.

- Open *Settings > Window Manager* and go to *Keyboard*
- select a empty case and click *edit*. A window should popup with ***Press any key***
- Press the key combination that isn't working **on your host machine**. In my case it wrote out `Alt`+`Shift`+`/`.
- Press the *clear* button and click again on *edit*.
- This time **use the wired keyboard on your client machine** and press the **exact same key combination**. In my case it wrote `Shift`+`Backslash`. (AHA! That's also the difference ...)
- Finally, edit your config file by adding the keystroke modification under `Section:`. I my case I had to add: `keystroke(Alt+Shift+/) = keystroke(Shift+Backslash,*)`.

I hope this can help others with my same issue!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.
KDE Neon Server and Windows10 client

https://github.com/symless/synergy-core/issues/4411#issuecomment-1035080808

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).